# Python Bubble Sort Code Explanation

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I am new to Python. How can we explain this code step by step. I couldn't understand some parts.

```
myList=[43,21,12,80,3,2,35]
end=len(myList)-1
while (end!=-1):
    swapped=-1
    for i in range(0,end):
        if myList[i]>myList[i+1]:
            temp=myList[i]
            myList[i]=myList[i+1]
            myList[i+1]=temp
            swapped=i
    end=swapped
print(myList)
```

Comment: Be specific. Exactly what don't you understand?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Is it the algorithm you're having a problem with, or the code itself?

Comment: I am sorry I am also new to stackoverflow. I don't have a problem with algorithm. For example in while loop can't we say while(True) instead of while(end!=-1) and why do we use swapped=-1. Thanks a lot

Comment: @flopoe Could you indicate to us where you originally got this code? Also, `-1` is acting as a sentinel: if the code is passed through without that changing to an index, it means that the whole list has been sorted. The author used `-1` as it's not a normal list index.

Comment: I saw this code on school slides and didn't make much sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `while True` would create an infinite loop **if** you forget to add code which will break the loop. In this case that break should only happen when `swapped` is still -1 at the end of the for-loop. Thus the following code:

```
myList=[43,21,12,80,3,2,35]
end=len(myList)-1
while True:
    swapped=-1
    for i in range(0,end):
        if myList[i]>myList[i+1]:
            temp=myList[i]
            myList[i]=myList[i+1]
            myList[i+1]=temp
            swapped=i
    if swapped == -1:
        break
print(myList)
```

If you count the number of lines of this example and compare them with the original you'll see that the original is 1 line shorter.
And checking against a value is in my opinion a better way-of-working than using `while True:` (or `while False:` for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

I think all your questions have been answered (they while(True) = infinite loop) and that swapped acts as 'is sorted' flag.

one thing that is very cool in python is that you do not need to have a temp variable as you do with in c, so you can change the if statement to:

```
if myList[i]>myList[i+1]:
    myList[i+1], myList[i] = myList[i], myList[i+1]
    swapped=i
```

or

```
if myList[i]>myList[i+1]:
    j = i + 1
    myList[j], myList[i] = myList[i], myList[j]
    swapped=i
```

if you do not want to compute i+1 twice

Also notice that range(0,-1) returns an empty list instead of trowing an exception

Comment: Thanks a lot I understood but one last question why do we need swapped=i?

Comment: @flopoe because swapped starts as -1 and is assigned to end, if you delete the swapped line you exit the loop after 1 iteration, the ingenious is that if nothing is swapped the list is obvious sorted and we are done